# How to use Swing Timer ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, timer, action, actionlistener

So I wanted to complete an action then pause for a certain amount of time then complete another action. I heard `Thread.sleep()` isn't good because it freezes the gui or something like that before completing the task. I know I need to use `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer` for one execution task but I really don't understand how. Here's the code. Credit is a `JButton`.

```
Credits.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public  void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
          Credits.setVisible(false);
          Oracle.setBounds(550,280,500,500);    
          Oracle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
          Oracle.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240,240,240));
          Oracle.setText("Credits To:");
          // I want to wait  or pause or sleep  for 5000 milliseconds  
          // Then Change The Icon 
 TimeClassAdd tcAdd = new TimeClassAdd();
    timer = new Timer(1000, tcAdd);
    timer.start();
    timerLabel.setText("IT HAS BEGUN");

  long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
  while (elaspedTime >= 5000) {
     break;}


 Oracle.setIcon(OraclePNG);


 }});
```

Comment: I don't see your attempt to try to use a Timer in your code posted. Please let's see what you've learned from the tutorials, and please show us exactly what problem you're having with your attempt. Also to help us now and to help yourself in the future, please edit your code and change your variable names to conform with Java naming conventions: class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter. This will make it **much** easier for others (**us**) to understand your code better.

Comment: Also, what is Oracle? Another JButton? A JLabel? If it's a different component such as a JLabel, you're probably better off using a CardLayout (and a Swing Timer) to swap components.

Comment: Then yes, use a CardLayout, and swap the components using a Swing Timer as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25276481/522444).

Answer (score 4):

As the example in the [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for `javax.swing.Timer` shows:

```
int delay = 5000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...Perform a task...
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Hint: Use the Java API docs if you're unsure how something works. It saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Wait so should i insert this code INSIDE the Credits Actionlistener

Comment: @SamuelMusa: you would use code like this wherever you needed to run your timer.

Comment: 1. The setReapeats methods apparently can't be found and the start method

Comment: Add `import javax.swing.Timer` to the top of your source file, if you haven't done that (and remove any other Timer class present).

Comment: There aren't any errors but it doesn't wait 5,000 millis